# My monerod server will not sync fully

Tags: synchronization

Title says, my server is stuck between 100-300 blocks behind. It has been oscillating for days like this. Here is a custom log output of how many blocks behind I am:

```
time:14:36:11 block:150
time:14:37:03 block:147
time:14:38:52 block:147
time:14:39:16 block:148
time:14:40:05 block:149
time:14:41:00 block:147
time:14:43:33 block:147
time:14:48:13 block:147
time:14:48:26 block:147
time:14:51:01 block:142
time:14:51:32 block:147
time:14:51:41 block:150
time:14:52:20 block:150
time:14:53:46 block:151
time:14:54:19 block:152
time:14:54:59 block:153
time:14:57:04 block:151
time:14:57:49 block:151
time:14:58:57 block:151
time:14:58:58 block:151
time:15:02:44 block:155
time:15:04:31 block:155
time:15:06:56 block:154
time:15:07:32 block:154
time:15:08:02 block:154
time:15:10:23 block:156
time:15:10:30 block:156
time:15:13:03 block:158
time:15:14:02 block:159
time:15:14:15 block:159
time:15:14:58 block:160
time:15:15:38 block:157
time:15:18:44 block:155
time:15:18:50 block:155
time:15:19:45 block:156
time:15:19:51 block:156
time:15:20:36 block:155
time:15:22:59 block:157
time:15:23:09 block:157
time:15:23:37 block:157
time:15:25:03 block:158
time:15:25:37 block:156
time:15:26:10 block:156
time:15:27:14 block:156
time:15:28:53 block:157
time:15:29:39 block:157
time:15:31:50 block:155
time:15:31:53 block:155
time:15:33:25 block:157
```

Things I tried to fix this are add  `--block-sync-size 10` to the service startup, and I also deleted the last 1000 blocks and resynced them using, `monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 1000`.

Any suggestions on what else to do?

#### update

I notice this error is common:

```
2017-12-28 15:57:30.056 [P2P0]  ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3042 Timestamp of block with id: <42ef1903bfb1677b7d2cf7eac866654a9b0e8cf0fc29bea9b9cf5165ee42cb12>, 1514484069, bigger than adjusted time + 2 hours
2017-12-28 15:57:30.056 [P2P0]  ERROR   verify  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3153 Block with id: <42ef1903bfb1677b7d2cf7eac866654a9b0e8cf0fc29bea9b9cf5165ee42cb12>
has invalid timestamp: 1514484069
```

paraphrased: `Timestamp of block bigger than adjusted time + 2 hours: block has invalid timestamp.`

Comment: Your server has the correct time, right?

Comment: haha thats a great thing to look into, I just reinstalled the OS.

Comment: That worked, my server synced within a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scoobybejesus recommended I make sure the server time was correct. 
I am on Arch Linux, so I ran `timedatectl set-ntp true` to sync my clock and the Monero server synced within a minute.

Looks like I forgot to run that when I installed the OS a few days ago.